# Having problems getting Console.WriteLine to work in a .NET Standard Library in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Can you use a Console.Write in a .NET Standard Library project, with a Windows Console project as the "driver" (has a Main function that calls the library)? In other words, this is a library that I have in a solution where there is a Windows console application referencing the .NET Standard Library project, and it crumps when it hits the `Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");` statement.

The error I get is an System.IO.FileNotFoundException:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Console, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

For the driver:

Target framework is: .NET 4.6.1 
Output type is: Console

For the library:

Target is .NET Standard 4.1 
Output type is: Class Library

So in main I am doing this:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      TextToConsole textToConsole = new TextToConsole();
      textToConsole.GetTextFromSource();
      textToConsole.WriteToDestination(); //gets to here and barfs.

   }
```

The WriteToDestination method looks like this:

```
    public void WriteToDestination()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(textString);//It barfs here and throws an
                                      //unhandled exception.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Surely you meant .NET Standard 1.4.  I got a repro for that.  I no longer know how this is supposed to work, afaik it should be the CLR that forwards the System.Console type to mscorlib.dll but that sure doesn't seem to work on .NET 4.7.  Whose install did not go well, I can't really trust my machine any more.  The workaround is to add the System.Console Nuget package to the EXE project, then it works fine.  Whether that is the correct workaround, hmm, hopefully not.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Stupid mistake. I had ***.NET Standard*** for the library's **target framework** originally, and that didn't match up to what I had for a ***target framework for the  executable*** (driver); a ***.NET Framework***. So for me, the .NET Standard library wasn't the right target framework.

I am guessing, that the library and the console application driver have to match, at least in this case. Visual Studio will not warn you if you mix target frameworks up. ***I changed the Library's target framework from .NET Standard, to .NET Framework***. Now it works!

Should a console application that has a .NET Framework 4.6.1 referencing a library with .NET Standard 1.4 work? I don't know, but I would love to know.

Comment: A dependent library can target .NET Standard while the consuming app can target .NET Framework.  The important thing is that the latter be a version which is compatible with the former.  Here's a link for compatibility:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard